# Problems with adMob

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have a question. I have a couple of android apps and getting revenue from ads. 
The first months I had about 60.000 impressions and a good cpm. Now I have more than 150.000 impressions and more clicks than before, but my eCPM is very low (0.04). I have already tried to add filters, change the refresh ratio and many other advices taken from articles and forums.

Is anyone happy with his advertisement plattform? Can you recommend me something to increase my eCPM or other advertisement network?

Comment: how increase your ecpm is not a stackoverflow question...

Comment: Not a programming related question.

Comment: Of course this has to do with programming...If I cannot pay my bills using my programming skills, I would not program at all.
Well, can you suggest me a website where I can ask this question at least?